# Where to buy quality clipart/icons for a product (e-card app) i plan to sell?

Tags: icons, photo, stock

I'm exhausted searching and reading all the licence options. Do any of u have some experience with this situation before?

I think what i need is W-EL (Web Usage Extended Licence), cause i need to be able to lisence my e-card templates.

Can someone direct me to the right place/es?

terms:
      A) Christmas graphics (clipart,icons,sets,collections)
      B) For commercial use (inside my templates for selling)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have free icons and icons for money for commercial apps http://www.iconfinder.com/

Answer (score 3):

For icons check out [IconExperience](http://www.iconexperience.com).

They have X Collection (for XP styled icons) and V Collection (for Vista / 7 styled icons, they look more like photos)